# Configurar botão no Bootstrap

Tags: php, yii

Sou novo no Yii e estou usando o Bootstrap. Configurei ele certinho porém ele está estranho na execução da página, por exemplo inseri um botão, ele é inserido normalmente só que em forma de link simples. Porquê?

```
<?php /* @var $this SiteController */ $this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name; ?> 
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbHeroUnit', array( 'heading'=>'Hello, world!', )); ?> 
<p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>  
<p>
   <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array( 'type'=>'primary', 'size'=>'large', 'label'=>'Learn more', )); ?>
</p> 
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Se puderes postar um exemplo do erro facilitará bastante para te ajudar

Comment: Realmente e pergunta não está muito bem formatada, mas acho que é cedo demais para pensarmos em fechar ela, vamos aguardar um tempo e a resposta do autor da pergunta.

Comment: Autor da pergunta, aproveite e veja este [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: coloquei uma imagem para ficar claro

Comment: Agora coloque o seu HTML também. sem ver como está colocando o botão, não há como ajudar

Comment: <?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbHeroUnit', array(
    'heading'=>'Hello, world!',
)); 

?>
 
    <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    <p><?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'primary',
        'size'=>'large',
        'label'=>'Learn more',
    )); ?></p>
 
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

Comment: isso foi o que o site me forneceu

Comment: @user3677610 por favor edite a sua pergunta e coloque esse [código](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25172/problemas-na-configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-bootstrap#comment46806_25172)

Comment: Tens aqui `'label'=>'Learn more',` uma virgula a mais, essa do fim. Experimenta sem ela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja na [documentação](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/) que por padrão ele é criado como link

A sua linha deve ficar assim:

***PHP***

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
   'buttonType' => 'button',
   'type' => 'primary',
   'size' => 'large',
   'label' => 'Learn more'
)); ?>
```

Aconselho também ao utilizar um array, no ultimo elemento não adicionar a virgula.

Comment: obrigado diego vieira deu certinho aqui :D

Comment: Disponha @user3677610, como você está aprendendo a framework é sempre interessante ficar com a documentação aberta do lado, é a forma mais fácil de domina-la!! um grande abraço e boa sorte com o projeto.

Comment: muito obrigado pelo conselho diego ;)